# How to validate data based on conditions

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
a = int(input("Enter mark of BIOLOGY: "))
b = int(input("Enter mark of CHEMISTRY: ")) 
c = int(input("Enter mark of PHYSICS: ")) 
sum = a + b + c 
x = sum 
y = 3 
avg = x / y
print("Total marks = ", sum) 
print("Average marks = ", avg)
```

I want to limit the user's input so it only accepts integers from 0 to 90.

Answer (score 1):

To limit the user's input to 0 to 90, you will need to repeatedly ask the user to re-input the data until it meets the 0 to 90 criteria. You can do that by implementing a `while` loop and then `break` if the criteria is met. Here's the code:

```
# Data validation for the variable "a"
while True:
    a = int(input("Enter mark of BIOLOGY: "))
    if 0 <= a <= 90:
         break
    else:
         print("The mark is not between 0 and 90. Please enter a new mark.")
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to limit the sum variable, at the end of your code you could simply put an if statement checking that the variable is within the boundary..

```
if sum > 90:
    sum = 90
elif sum < 0:
    sum = 0
```

Comment: Although this may work, what if the user unintentionally puts a grade outside the range of 0 to 90? It's safer to ask the user repeatedly imho.

Comment: It all depends on what the purpose of the code is, which the asker didn't provide much information on.  I do see that your suggestion is likely what the user meant when asking though.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will ensure that the user inputs the number in the specified range:

```
while True:
    a = int(input("enter mark of BIOLOGY = "))
    if 0 <= a <= 90:
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid mark. Please try again.")

while True:
    b = int(input("enter mark of CHEMISTRY = "))
    if 0 <= b <= 90:
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid mark. Please try again.")

while True:
    c = int(input("enter mark of PHYSICS = "))
    if 0 <= c <= 90:
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid mark. Please try again.")

sum = a + b + c 
x = sum 
y = 3 
avg = x / y
print("total marks = ", sum) 
print("average marks = ", avg)
```

This will ensure the variables `a`, `b`, and `c` are between 0-90.